# Collision Detection algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

**This is the algorithm that I'm trying to solve:**

There are n circular organisms with radii r0,r1,..rn-1 . During each second, two organisms with radii ri and rj and (chosen randomly and equiprobably) collide to form a new, bigger organism with radius ri+rj. enter image description here

Given the radii for n creatures and an integer,k, print a single floating-point number denoting the expected total area of all the creatures after k seconds.

**Input Format**

The first line contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of n and k. The second line contains n space-separated integers describing the respective values of r0,r1,..rn-1

**Constraints**

1 < n < 10^5

0< k < n-1

1 < ri < 10^4

An answer is considered to be correct if it has a relative error of at most 10^-9.

**Output Format**

Print a single floating-point number denoting the expected sum of the creatures' areas after k collisions.

**Sample Input 0**

3 1

1 2 3

**Sample Output 0**

67.0206432766

[image]

**Sample Input 1**

3 2

1 2 3

**Sample Output 1**

113.0973355292

**Explanation 1**

We have n = 3 organisms with radii in {1, 2, 3}. After k = 2 seconds, two collisions take

place and we're left with one circle that has a radius of 6. We then print the total area taken up by the remaining organism, which is pi (3.14159265359) * 6^2 = 113.0973355292.

**I started writing out my code as folowing:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int k = in.nextInt();

    int[] r = new int[n];
    for(int r_i=0; r_i < n; r_i++){
        r[r_i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    double sum=0;
    double avrage=0;
    double pi = 3.1415926535;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int sumj=0;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                 if(j!=i)
                     sumj=sumj+r[j];
                     System.out.println(sumj);
            }

        sum=sum+pi*Math.pow((r[i]),2)+pi*Math.pow(sumj,2);
   }
    avrage=sum/n;
    System.out.println(avrage);
}
}
```

The problem is that I'm not sure where should I use the parameter k(seconds) to solve this problem.
It works only for k=1(after second).
What should I change that the code will work for k=2(after 2 seconds) or k is a another number(after x seconds)?

Comment: Is this a programming contest that is still active?

Comment: kind of ...........

Comment: then shouldn't you wait until it has ended? It is quite unfair to ask for help whereas other contestants aim to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: You can't use brute force for this, constraints in such problems are added in such a way that you have to optimize your algorithm otherwise it won't finish in reasonable time. For the given constraints your current loop will runs for 10 billion times.

Comment: wow. Where should I start?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: You could try monte carlo simulation, but I don't know if you get sufficient accuracy in reasonable time.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w31/challenges/colliding-circles ends in 2 days

Comment: You should wait until the end of the contest - they will publish correct solutions.